# How to extract certain under specific condition in pandas? (Sentimental analysis)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

[image]

The picture is what my dataframe looks like. I have user_name, movie_name and time column. I want to extract only rows that are first day of certain movie. For example, if movie a's first date in the time column is 2018-06-27, i want all the rows in that date and if movie b's first date in the time column is 2018-06-12, i only want those rows. How would i do that with pandas?

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs? I believe they cover this, or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that *time* column is of *datetime* type. If not, convert this
column calling *pd.to_datetime*.

Then run:

```
df.groupby('movie_name').apply(lambda grp:
    grp[grp.time.dt.date == grp.time.min().date()])
```

*Groupby* groups the source DataFrame into grops concerning particular films.

Then *grp.time.min().date()* computes the minimal (first) date from the
current group.

And finally the whole lamda function returns only rows from this date
(also from the current group).

The same for other groups of rows (films).