# How to sort dataframe by time and other condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with following columns: `movie_name`, `date`, `comment`.

The date format is like this(example): `2018-06-27T09:09:00Z`.

I want to make a new dataframe that contains ONLY first date of a certain movie.

For example, for movie a, the first date maybe `2018-09-11T:02:02:00Z`, in this case, i want all rows on 2018-09-11 for movie a. How would i do this when there are multiple movies with different dates?

Comment: It is same like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597811/how-to-extract-certain-under-specific-condition-in-pandas-sentimental-analysis)

Comment: Have you tried using `date` instead of `datetime` in the type part of the database?

Comment: How would i accomplish this with date  type?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do:

```
# create a new df
new_df = old_df['date'].copy()

# get the date
new_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(new_df['date']).dt.date

# first date of movie
new_df.groupby('movie_name')['date'].first()
```

Comment: Yes, i have transformed the date, but how would i make a new dataframe that contains ONLY first date of a certain movie? For example,if the first date of movie 'a' is on 2018-09-11, how would i only extract rows with that certain date . How would i do this when there are multiple movies with different dates?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt
df['My Time Format'] = dt['Given time].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"),"%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: Yes, i have transformed the dates, but i still don't know how to  make a new dataframe that contains rows for first date of a certain movie.

Comment: did you use df.groupby(['My Time Format'])